# busybox у digitalocen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, digitalocean

Сделал resize droplet для убунту сервера.
После включения вижу такую картинку
[image: Консоль]

Пытался гуглить, пишут необходимо ввести exit, после чего можно будет монтировать диск, но у меня это не вышло.
[image: После exit]

fstab:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

mount vda1[image: mount]

Требуется помощь для запуска сервера.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможно, почему-то просто сменился id основного диска. Попробуйте вывести /etc/fstab и отредактировать вопрос, приложив вывод, в идеале надо будет просто с помощью sed заменить одну строчку.

Comment: Добавил скриншот с командой cat  /etc/fstab

Comment: @JegorBogomolov примонтируй сначала корневую ФС куда-нить и смотри в ней... скорее всего неправильный uid прописан не в fstab, а в загрузчике...

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вас не затруднит немного детальнее описать, так как с подобным я не сталкивался.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я жду ответ от тех поддержки 14 часов. Проект в простое, я теряю деньги и репутацию, поэтому решил уже сам действовать, а не ждать тех поддержку. которой насрать на простой у клиентов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Дисклеймер] Дальнейший текст подразумевает, что человек в точности понимает, что он делает и может корректировать команды под свои нужды, все неточности могут привести к плачевным результатам.

`/dev/sdXX` -- диск с root ФС.

Примерная последовательность действий:

```
mkdir -p /mnt
mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
# <монтирование всех остальных стандартных ФС /usr, /var, /boot, если они есть>
mount -o bind /dev/ /mnt/dev
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys

chroot /mnt /bin/bash

update-grub
ls -l /dev/disks/by-id
#<редактирование /etc/fstab>

exit
reboot
```

Это всё сработает, только если диск поменял `uid`... Что такое `resize droplet` — я не знаю... Если корневая ФС была удалена или повреждена до нечитаемости, то простой умозрительный рецепт дать не получится...

Comment: /dev/sdXX - тут вместо XX, должна быть файловая система, что-то вроде sda1?

Comment: @JegorBogomolov, да, конечно...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, наверно, всё-таки не файловая система, а **раздел** блочного устройства, **содержащий** файловую систему.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, что бы монтировать /mnt в /sdXX, он должен существовать? А в df у меня этого нет.

Comment: @JegorBogomolov, df выводит данные только по уже примонтированным ФС. Надо знать, где находится корень или монтировать всё подряд пока не попадётся что-то похожее...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, //соревнование terminology-nazi объявляется открытым;)// наверное, всё-таки *блочное устройство, соответствующее разделу диска, содержащего корневую файловую систему*

Comment: @Fat-Zer, «диск» — это как раз и есть блочное устройство. а разделы — это когда-то в древние времена добавленная как бы эмуляция как бы нескольких блочных устройств как бы внутри «настоящего» блочного устройства. но мой комментарий относился совершенно не к этому, а к тому, что «что-то вроде sda1» — это **точно не** файловая система.

Comment: Добавил скриншот, vda1 выдал о своём существовании, но при попытки mount выдаёт ошибку

Comment: @JegorBogomolov, ни какой ошибки нет... только сообщение ядра о нормальном монтировании... ещё раз, если не понимаешь, что **именно** ты  делаешь, для чего нужно каждое действие и какой результат ожидается от него, то лучше не начинай... почитай документацию, потренируйся сначала на карманных виртуалках, или ещё на чём-то... да, в виртуальных системах могут быть свои особенности, о которых я мог не подумать...

Comment: Я сейчас делаю на копии сервера, поэтому если что-то сломаю, последствий не будет.

Comment: <монтирование всех остальных стандартных ФС /usr, /var, /boot, если они есть> - Можно ещё комментарий, как стандартные разделы монтировать в ФС?

Comment: @JegorBogomolov как обычно, `mount /dev/<usr_device> /mnt/usr` для остальных аналогично... это всё строго по необходимости...

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо. Всё получилось!